# Can't find GDK::InterpType members in gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm, gdkpixbuf

I'm trying to make a `Gtk::Image` widget display a picture from a file, but prevent the widget from expanding in size, so I'm loading it from a `Gdk::Pixbuf` and then scaling the picture. I'm using `Gdk::Pixbuf` instead of `GdkPixBuf` because the latter one works on regular pointers, but `Gtk::Image` requires a `Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf>`. (Just mentioning all this in case there's a better way to achieve what I'm doing that I'm unaware of.)

```
auto pixbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("/home/raitis/Music/WRLD/Awake EP/cover.jpg");
auto scaled = pixbuf->scale_simple(48, 48, Gdk::InterpType::NEAREST);
image->set(scaled);
```

Anyway, problem is that although I'm following the [documentation for `Gdk::Pixbuf`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGdk_1_1Pixbuf.html#a73e2c7be0469e402cc20fbad27015767), line 2 in my code generate the error:

```
error: ‘NEAREST’ is not a member of ‘Gdk::InterpType’
auto scaled = pixbuf->scale_simple(48, 48, Gdk::InterpType::NEAREST);
                                                            ^~~~~~~
```

Trying `GDK_INTERP_NEAREST` instead also leads to an error. :(

```
no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘GdkInterpType’ to ‘Gdk::InterpType’
```

Comment: If anyone knows how I could query the g++ compiler to tell me what ARE members of Gdk::InterpType, please let me know!

Comment: GDK_INTERP_TYPE is an enum, for test purposes only, try with an equivalent `int`, let's say 0. Does it compile?

Comment: @JoséFonte nope, still getting a type error `invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Gdk::InterpType’`

Comment: Try with `Gdk::INTERP_NEAREST`

Comment: @JoséFonte Holy moly! I thought I had tried every possible name I could think of, but no – your suggestion worked! :D Feel free to leave it as an answer and I'll accept it! Huge thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stable [gtkmm](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/) gdkmm documentation, [Gdk::InterpType](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/group__gdkmmEnums.html#ga709a35a3eb48c0b819041e3414715facaa75a2321f8f1457aa426a6ab0c0a0a90) members are:

> **INTERP_NEAREST**
>
> Nearest neighbor sampling; this is the fastest and lowest quality
>   mode. Quality is normally unacceptable when scaling down, but may be OK when
>   scaling up.
>
> **INTERP_TILES**
>
> This is an accurate simulation of the PostScript image operator
>   without any interpolation enabled.
>
> Each pixel is rendered as a tiny parallelogram of solid color, the
>   edges of which are implemented with antialiasing. It resembles nearest
>   neighbor for enlargement, and bilinear for reduction.
>
> **INTERP_BILINEAR**
>
> Best quality/speed balance; use this mode by default.
>
> Bilinear interpolation. For enlargement, it is equivalent to
>   point-sampling the ideal bilinear-interpolated image. For reduction,
>   it is equivalent to laying down small tiles and integrating over the
>   coverage area.
>
> **INTERP_HYPER**
>
> This is the slowest and highest quality reconstruction function.
>
> It is derived from the hyperbolic filters in Wolberg's "Digital Image
>   Warping", and is formally defined as the hyperbolic-filter sampling
>   the ideal hyperbolic-filter interpolated image (the filter is designed
>   to be idempotent for 1:1 pixel mapping).

And from the documentation of the [Gdk::Pixbuf](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Pixbuf.html), in the `scale_simple` method you'll find a reference to the interpolation type:

> Leaves src unaffected. interp_type should be **Gdk::INTERP_NEAREST** if
>   you want maximum speed (but when scaling down **Gdk::INTERP_NEAREST** is
>   usually unusably ugly). The default interp_type should be
>   **Gdk::INTERP_BILINEAR** which offers reasonable quality and speed.

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that I was reading the unstable documentation for gtkmm instead of the stable one (which I didn't realize, since I thought I was just using the latest version, which I wasn't). Thanks!

Comment: @rusins Glad to help :) Good luck with your project!